# Most universal non-abelian factor group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, limits-colimits

$\require{AMScd}$
I understand that given a group $G$, all homomorphisms from $G$ to an abelian group factor through the [abelianization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization) of $G$, i.e. maps $G\to A$ factor through projection $G\to G/\left[G, G\right]$.

I was wondering if you could define the same for codomain groups that are not abelian. I am not even sure if “largest non-abelian factor” is well-defined, but I came up with this idea.

Consider $G_0 = G$ in the sequence
$\require{tikzcd}$
\begin{CD}
    G_0 @>\zeta_1>> G_1 @>\zeta_2>> \cdots
\end{CD}
where $G_{i + 1}$  is $G_i / Z(G_i)$ and $\zeta_i$ is projection mod $Z(G_i)$ (alternatively, visualize a herringbone of ses's).

What if at some point 
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>\zeta^*>> G^* @>\zeta{^*}'\, \overset{\huge\color{red}?}{=} \,\,\mathrm{id}\,>> G^*
\end{CD}

Certainly this sequence must end if $G$ is finitely generated. If that isn't the case, then my question concerns $G^* = \displaystyle\lim_{\longrightarrow} G_i$.

What exactly lies at the end of this tunnel? As far as I can tell, projection onto $G^*$ uniquely factors all epimorphisms $G\to \text{a non-abelian group}$. Is that right?

Is $Z(G)$ dual to $[G, G]$? What does $G^*$, if it exists, say about $G$?

Comment: Well, you'd have to factor the identity map from $G$ to $G$. In particular if $G$ is nonabelian, you won't be able to find a nontrivial quotient that the identity factors through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already your favourite non-abelian group of order $p^3$ ($p$ any prime) and the identity function show that taking the epimorphisms to *non-abelian* groups does **not** work (as commented by Grumpy Parsnip).

Try epimorphisms to **center-free** groups instead!

For understanding your $G^*$ take a look at the kernels of your maps $\zeta_1:G_0\to G_1$, $\zeta_2\circ\zeta_1:G_0\to G_2$, $\zeta_3\circ\zeta_2\circ\zeta_1:G_0\to G_3$, $\dots$, which are the elements of [the upper central series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series#Upper_central_series) (read also the following section "Connection between lower and upper central series" in the wikipedia for your last question).

Comment: Hint: The image of the center of $G$ under an epimorphism is contained in the center of the image, so if the image has trivial center, the center of $G$ is contained in the kernel of the epimorphism. Now induct.